Energy loss on increasing moment of inertia
A body connected to a inextensible, massless string which is being spun around by a man in a circular path.
The rope is then slowly released by the man from his fingers and stopped at a certain radius. (The inertia of the object pulls the rope out, as a result the radius of the circular path increases.)
The initial angular momentum of the object is L given by Iω where ω and I are the initial angular velocity and moment of inertia respectively. If the moment of inertia was doubled due to the release of the rope the angular velocity will be halved to keep the angular momentum constant.
But now if we look at the energy equation for rotation energy which is $\frac{1}{2}Iω^2$ the final energy comes out to be half that of the initial energy. Where was the energy lost?
The increase in the length of the rope was spontaneous so it couldn't have been lost there. Even if we consider work being done against the centripetal force in the ground frame the energy dissipated comes out to be only a part of the energy lost.

The increase "was spontaneous" does not mean anything. If the man slowly released the rope then there was friction between the rope and the fingers holding and releasing it.

The situation that has been described is in some ways equivalent to that of a planet moving in an elliptical orbit around the Sun where the force on the planet is central and hence does not exert a torque on the planet which in turn means that angular momentum is conserved.
As the planet moves away from the Sun the planet loses kinetic energy and the planet and Sun system gains gravitational potential energy or put another way, negative work is done on the planet alone system.
The equivalent of the gain in gravitational potential energy for the planet and Sun system is a loss of mechanical energy in the body and man system or negative work done on the body alone system.
The rope is then slowly released by the man from his fingers and stopped at a certain radius means that the man's fingers must be exerting a friction force on the rope whilst the rope is slipping through the fingers and thus work is done resulting in the generation of heat with the body losing kinetic energy as it moves to a larger radius "orbit".
